# Convert dynamic array to static

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-xe2

Because of compatibility purpose, I need to pass my dynamic array (of Double) to the obsolete type `p_vektor` defined as

```
p_vektor=array[1..50] of double;
```

Although the both declarations differ from the first index declaration, the used type is the same. I wrote the following code to copy the arrays, but it fails.

```
function DoubleArrayToPVektor(const aArray: TArray<Double>): p_vektor;
begin
  Move(aArray[Low(aArray)], Result[Low(Result)], Length(aArray));
end;
```

As the result, only the first element is copied successfully. Is there any quick way to copy the array without using an alternative, iterative solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move accepts the number of bytes. You pass the number of elements. You need to pass

```
Length(aArray)*SizeOf(aArray[0])
```

as the number of bytes to be copied.

Do make sure that you check that the length of `aArray` is no more than 50.

Also be aware that you are not initialising all elements of the result array. Whether that matters only you can judge.